# PayPal Express Checkout Enhanced/Responsive layout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

Is there a way in the PayPal account settings/PHP code for SetExpressCheckout to force PayPal's new enhanced/responsive layout? Currently I am stuck with [image: classic] when I want this one [image: enhanced]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after SetExpressCheckout response, you need to redirect your client to https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=

Comment: Thanks for the response. When trying this it starts off with the new ajax spinner as if it's going to work but then redirects back to the old checkout (the URL looks like this after the redirect: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&force_sa=true&fallback=1&token=)

Comment: I found out how, for me I had to go /checkout/2?token= but doesn't look like I'm going to be able to use the new checkout as it appears the callback for shipping options is not supported

Comment: can you explain how to make the page appear with enhanced view for paypal

Comment: this doesn't work for me, what I found out is when you use the documented /cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout, if your API call contains either item details or recurring payment, it uses old layout, otherwise it uses new layout.